# Fetching large value from the database

Tags: java, mysql

Sorry for this noob question but I really don't know what to search and how to solve it.I have a table structure like this:

[image]

This is only a part of my table.

`budget_cost` has `1000000000.1` literal

I tried to fetch the values

```
while( result.next() )
{
   ProjectBean projectBean = new ProjectBean();
   ...
   projectBean.setBudgetCost( result.getDouble( "budget_cost" ) );
   ...
}
```

my model has setter and getter of each variables

```
public class ProjectBean
{
    ...
    private double profitRate;
    private double vatRate;
    private double fees;
    private double budgetCost;
    private String dateDeadline;
    ...
}
```

I tried to print the `budgetCost` and it prints `1.0E9`

**I need it to display `1000000000.1` what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong.  try using NumberFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: You should use `BigDecimal` here and for any currency values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing your question: take a look at the class `java.lang.DecimalFormat` - this will allow you to define some output-format for your float-values.

But it is usually a bad idea to store monetary values in binary floatinf-point-types (like `float` or `double`) since you will run into rounding-issues as soon as you use values like `0.1` (decimal). Better use somthing like `java.math.BigDecimal` or (I like that even better) a custom-class for storing fixed-point-values that internally uses an `ìnt` or a `long` and a some scale.